# Is there a way to change wallpaper automatically at regular intervels in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-center, desktop-background

There is this option to change wallpaper automatically at a certain interval of choice in MS Windows. Is there a way to do such a thing in Ubuntu 18.04 or later? Use all pictures in a specific folder perhaps rolling them after a selected time.

Comment: It is possible by a simple script to generate the xml file first and then use that generated xml file..

Comment: Yes, there is. Please don't ask yes/no questions...